# Join tables where one table needs to be filtered on 'latest version'

Tags: sql, ms-access, query-optimization

I am working on a project where data is located in many tables. For one query I need to pull data from a join of 5 tables. The issue is that one of the tables need to be filtered on 'latest version' before joining (Stored in ANALYSIS.VERSION). I have been able to accomplish this with an ugly and inefficient subquery that I would like to replace. Here is that section of the query:

```
INNER JOIN (                                   
    SELECT * FROM ANALYSIS WHERE               
        (NAME & '/' & VERSION)  IN    (        
            SELECT NAME & '/' & MAX(VERSION)   
            FROM ANALYSIS                      
            GROUP BY NAME                      
         )                                     
    ) AS a                                     
ON                                             
    a.NAME=ps.ANALYSIS)
```

As I am working with MS Access I do not think that I can get something like this to work:

```
INNER JOIN (                                   
    SELECT * FROM ANALYSIS WHERE               
        (NAME, VERSION)  IN (NAME, MAX(VERSION) GROUP BY NAME                      
    ) AS a
```

Any suggestions?

The entire query looks like this:

```
SELECT                                                                                                   
    ps.ANALYSIS AS [Analysis],                                                                           
    ps.STAGE AS [Stage],                                                                                 
    a.ANALYSIS_TYPE AS [Anal type],                                                                      
    IIF(a.CK_ANL_MTD_SPEC='',                                                                            
        a.CK_ANL_MTD_GEN,                                                                                
        a.CK_ANL_MTD_SPEC                                                                                
    ) AS [AM],                                                                                           
    ps.COMPONENT AS [Components],                                                                        
    SWITCH(                                                                                              
        ps.SPEC_RULE='Result <= MAX'       ,CHRW(8804) & ps.MAX_VALUE,                                   
        ps.SPEC_RULE='Result >= MIN'       ,CHRW(8805) & ps.MIN_VALUE,                                   
        ps.SPEC_RULE='MIN <= Result <= MAX',ps.MIN_VALUE & ' ' & CHRW(8212) & ' ' & ps.MAX_VALUE,        
        ps.SPEC_RULE='Equal to'            ,ps.TEXT_VALUE,                                               
        ps.SPEC_RULE='Result is One of'    ,Replace(ps.TEXT_VALUE,' ',', '),                             
        ps.SPEC_RULE='MIN < Result < MAX'  ,'>' & ps.MIN_VALUE & ' ' & CHRW(8212) & ' <' & ps.MAX_VALUE, 
        ps.SPEC_RULE='MIN < Result <= MAX' ,'>' & ps.MIN_VALUE & ' ' & CHRW(8212) & ' ' & ps.MAX_VALUE,  
        ps.SPEC_RULE='MIN <= Result < MAX' , ps.MIN_VALUE & ' ' & CHRW(8212) & ' <' & ps.MAX_VALUE,      
        ps.SPEC_RULE='Not Equal to'        ,CHRW(8800) & ps.TEXT_VALUE,                                  
        ps.SPEC_RULE='Result < MAX'        ,'<' & ps.MAX_VALUE,                                          
        ps.SPEC_RULE='Result > MIN'        ,'>' & ps.MIN_VALUE,                                          
        ps.SPEC_RULE='Result is Like'      ,'LIKE ' & ps.TEXT_VALUE,                                     
        ps.SPEC_RULE='Result is Not Like'  ,'NOT LIKE ' & ps.TEXT_VALUE,                                 
        ps.SPEC_RULE='Result is Not One of','NOT ' & Replace(ps.TEXT_VALUE,' ',', '),                    
    ) & IIF(ps.SPEC_RULE='','Report result','' &                                                         
        (                                                                                                
        SELECT                                                                                           
            ' ' & u.DISPLAY_STRING FROM UNITS AS u                                                       
        WHERE                                                                                            
            u.UNIT_CODE=ps.UNITS                                                                         
        AND                                                                                              
            u.UNIT_CODE<>'NONE'                                                                          
        )                                                                                                
    )  AS [Specification],                                                                               
    c.CLAMP_LOW & c.CLAMP_HIGH as [Clamp],                                                               
    '' as [Comment],                                                                                     
    pg.REVISION_NUMBER                                                                                   
FROM ((((PRODUCT_SPEC AS ps                                                                              
INNER JOIN PROD_GRADE_STAGE AS psg                                                                       
ON                                                                                                       
    psg.GRADE=ps.GRADE AND                                                                               
    psg.PRODUCT=ps.PRODUCT AND                                                                           
    psg.VERSION=ps.VERSION AND                                                                           
    psg.ANALYSIS=ps.ANALYSIS AND                                                                         
    psg.SAMPLING_POINT=ps.SAMPLING_POINT AND                                                             
    psg.STAGE=ps.STAGE)                                                                                  
INNER JOIN (                                                                                             
    SELECT * FROM ANALYSIS WHERE                                                                         
        (NAME & '/' & VERSION)  IN    (                                                                  
            SELECT NAME & '/' & MAX(VERSION)                                                             
            FROM ANALYSIS                                                                                
            GROUP BY NAME                                                                                
         )                                                                                               
    ) AS a                                                                                               
ON                                                                                                       
    a.NAME=ps.ANALYSIS)                                                                                  
INNER JOIN COMPONENT AS c                                                                                
ON                                                                                                       
    c.ANALYSIS=a.NAME AND                                                                                
    c.NAME=ps.COMPONENT AND                                                                              
    c.VERSION=a.VERSION)                                                                                 
INNER JOIN PRODUCT_GRADE AS pg                                                                           
ON                                                                                                       
    pg.GRADE=ps.GRADE AND                                                                                
    pg.PRODUCT=ps.PRODUCT AND                                                                            
    pg.VERSION=ps.VERSION AND                                                                            
    pg.SAMPLING_POINT=ps.SAMPLING_POINT)                                                                 
WHERE                                                                                                    
    ps.GRADE='#sGrade#' AND                                                                              
    psg.GRADE='#sGrade#' AND                                                                             
    ps.PRODUCT='#sSpec#' AND                                                                             
    psg.PRODUCT='#sSpec#' AND                                                                            
    ps.VERSION=#sVersion# AND                                                                            
    psg.VERSION=#sVersion#                                                                               
ORDER BY                                                                                                 
    psg.ORDER_NUMBER,                                                                                    
    ps.ORDER_NUMBER
```

This is a generic query that is used for different inputs of #sGrade#, #sSpec# and #sVersion#.

Comment: When I have a long sql query and my older Access is bugging out I break the query into parts.  I usually start at the innermost query and work my way out to start just before the first bug.  then I feed each query as a source to the next outermost query.  I often use a little vba to run the queries sequentially, as a single function I can call anywhere, rather than wrapping them in one still too long sql call.  Omitting details my query processor gets confused by complexity and needs to be fed in chunks but is then quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

try to avoid `IN` operator it is not very efficient, consider that it works more like a sintetic syntax for a sequence of `OR` so

```
column1 IN (val1, val2, val3)
```

is like

```
column1 = val1 OR column1 = val2 OR column1 = val3
```

and when the list of values is big it will be a bad solution

Try this

```
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT NAME, VERSION, ANALYSIS_TYPE, CK_ANL_MTD_SPEC, CK_ANL_MTD_GEN
    FROM ANALYSIS A 
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM (
            SELECT NAME, MAX(VERSION) LV
            FROM ANALYSIS L
            GROUP BY NAME
        ) L
        WHERE L.name = A.name AND L.LV = A.version
    )
) AS a ON a.NAME=ps.ANALYSIS)
```

The `EXISTS` operator will be translated in a semi-join and it is more efficient